# Function to Round Variable Values - PHP

Tags: php, function, rounding

I need to change several variable values by rounding them, and while it works if I specify each variable individually I'm having trouble getting it to do the same thing in a function.

**Single Variable** 
Result = 9.5 *(Works correctly)*

```
$var = 9.54;
If ($var != NULL AND $var !== "") {
   $var = round($var , 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); 
}
echo $var;
```

**Function** Result = 9.54 *(Doesn't work correctly)*

```
$a = 9.54;
function RoundDecimal($var) {
   If ($var != NULL AND $var !== "") {
      $var = round($var , 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); 
   }
}
RoundDecimal($a); // Calls function
echo $a;
```

Comment: And you want to pass the variables by reference, so change your function header to: `function RoundDecimal(&$var) {`

Comment: include in your function return $var

Comment: @Rizier123 - That did it :-D Would you mind explaining that to me?

Comment: Because you didn't passed your argument [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)!

Comment: @Rizier123 - Thanks for explaining something new to me :-) btw, If you want to add it as an answer, I'd love to accept it :-)

Comment: @Rizier123 - Is there something else I need to do in order to insert the modified values into a db? It's performing properly before inserting them, but it then inserts the original values in the db.

Comment: No ?! You just need to change the value before you insert it

Comment: @Rizier123 I realized that it seems to be inherent to 'Serialize'. Now if I could only figure out how to get around that ;-)